# Unrecognized selector mutableCopyWithZone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am following the tutorial for Core Data from this site
http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-to-core-data/

But I am getting the following error:

**2016-06-23 17:55:11.905 MyStore[6020:596233] -[NSAsynchronousFetchResult
mutableCopyWithZone
:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8950e12eb0**

I placed a breakpoint and the error seems to come from the following procedure.

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    
    //Fetch the devices from the persistent store.
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Device"];
    self.devices = [[managedObjectContext executeRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy]; //error here
    
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

I have the property "devices" declared as a NSMutableArray.

Any type of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Somehow, your `executeRequest:error:` call results in `NSAsynchronousFetchResult` instance. This may happen, if you use `NSAsynchronousFetchRequest ` instead of `NSFetchRequest`, but in code you post it's not the case. You can read more about async fetching here - https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/new-in-core-data-and-iOS-8-asynchronous-fetching/

Comment: Thanks Boris, I realized that :) Look at my answer lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I was using the incorrect method when I was following the procedure.

The method I should have used was **executeFetchRequest** and by mistake I was using **executeRequest**. The first one returns indeed an NSArray but the other one returns a NSPersistentStoreResult.

Here are are the methods.

```
- (nullable NSArray *)executeFetchRequest:(NSFetchRequest *)request error:(NSError **)error;
- (nullable __kindof NSPersistentStoreResult *)executeRequest:(NSPersistentStoreRequest*)request error:(NSError **)error NS_AVAILABLE(10_10, 8_0);
```

Thanks to the help of Volodymyr I was able to check that my object returned was indeed the type I was expecting which **was not** and from there I could have changed the method but then I discovered that the object returned was a more complex one and has an NSArray property I could use.

So here is my code with my tests :)

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    //Fetch the devices from the persistent store.
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Device"];

    id whatAreYou = [managedObjectContext executeRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", [whatAreYou class]); // turns out you are a NSPersistentStoreResult
    // lucky for me you are have finalResult property that returns an NSArray. :)

    self.devices = [[whatAreYou finalResult] mutableCopy]; //no more errors here :)

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Thanks a lot for the help. Checking for the object type is something I will add to my debugging tools from now on :)

Answer (score 3):

Under `mutableCopy` is layering `mutableCopyWithZone`. Thats mean that object that returns from your fetch request does not implements method `mutableCopyWithZone`. You can try to use instead `copy` method. Still you need to check what object was return and if this object implements methods `mutableCopyWithZone` or `copyWithZone`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried the copy but it did not work. The object been return  is NSArray as per this - (nullable NSArray *)executeFetchRequest:(NSFetchRequest *)request error:(NSError **)error;

Comment: Can you separate this last line into two line actions. In first you will get fetched object and in second do your copping. As well after you fetched object check its class to be sure it's what you are thinking it is. Also check if it's nil. Do you know how to perform such check?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response and the help. I did exactly as you said and I was getting back a different object :) See my answer for full details.